# MySQL SUM of two rows with condition

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sum

I am a beginner in MySQL and I need your help.
I have something like this:

```
ID  Project  Type  Amount
1   1        I     5000
2   1        D     1000
3   2        I     3500
4   3        I     4300
5   3        D     1200
```

And I want something like this (the difference between the amounts of I type and D type for the same project; the D type is not always present):

```
Project  Amount
1        4000
2        3500
3        3100
```

Comment: is project only has 2 value which is means low and high ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using `case` for taking `Amount` with `+` or `-`:

```
  select Project as Project,
         sum(case  
               when Type = 'I' then
                 Amount
               when Type = 'D' then 
                -Amount 
             end case) as Amount
    from MyTable
group by Project
--    order by Project -- uncomment this if you want sorted cursor
```

Comment: he ask the diffrent value between 2 values,

Answer (score 1):

Try this;)

```
select
    Project,
    sum(if(Type = 'I', Amount, -Amount)) as Amount
from table1
group by Project
```

[SQLFiddle DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59c72e/3)

Comment: Probably, `sum (if(Type = 'I', Amount, -Amount))` is a better implementation of the idea

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Hmm, you're right. Updated it. Thanks.

Comment: please, remember that `if` being *shorter* is however *RDBMS specific* (that's why I prefer `case`)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I remember that, Thanks again for this priceless suggestion.